# Carol's father was 24 years old when Carol was born. Now he is four times as old as carol. How old is carol?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Carol's father was 24 years old when Carol was born. Now he is four times as old as carol. How old is carol?

I don't know how to approach this question. Thank You and help is appreciated

Comment: let Carol's age now be $x$. Then the father's age now is ...?

Comment: Let $C$ be the age of Carol. Then $4\times C$ is the age of her father which is $24+C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence is telling us that the father is older than Carol by $24$ years.

The second sentence is telling us that the father is now older than Carol by three times her age (as his age is four times her age).

Thus, Carol is now $24/3=8$ years old.

Comment: Is there a way to solve this algebraically?

Comment: @AspaeringStar7 Yes, of course; I would refer to other answers and comments, which attempt to do exactly that. I explicitly tried to avoid using algebra and to come up with a solution that could be understood at a very elementary level.

Comment: Algebraic solution: label father's age with $x$, Carol's age with $y$ and then set up the system of equations: $x - y = 24$ and $x = 4y$, then solve...

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ be the age of the father and $C$ be the age of Carol. We know that $F=C+24$ since the father was 24 when Carol was born. When is $F=4C?$ When $3C=24.$ That is, when Carol is 8 years old (at which time her father will be 32).

Comment: Thank You i understand!

Answer (score 0):

father = f
age of carol = c

We have the ratio:
$\frac{24 + c}{c} = 4$
Therefore, $c = 8$.

Carol is 8 years old.

Answer (score 0):

You can express the same thought using only a single variable.  Let Carol's current age be $x$.  We can express the father's age in two different ways:  $4x=x+24$.  This tells us $3x=24$ so $x=8$.

I'm making this elementary point because it's a pretty common technique to prove identities in a variety of settings by calculating a figure (dad's age) in two different ways ($4x$ and $x+24$) and noting that the two different evaluations must yield the same result.

For example, this is a method that can be used to prove

$$\sum_{m=0}^n \binom{n}{m} = 2^n$$

by realizing these are two different ways to count the number of subsets of a set of size $n$.